# Flag is not changed into helpful, But the question has been put on hold as flag suggested

Tags: discussion, flags

I have flagged a question here with `off-topic` [which is the best resource for learning android app development [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599796/which-is-the-best-resource-for-learning-android-app-development). This question has been put on hold. But when i see my helpful flag history it says active, But the question is closed as off-topic and in my flag i have suggested that. Why it isn't changed to helpful? Here is my [flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3110424).

Comment: We can't see your flag summary page -- only moderators can :) I'll let a moderator answer though, as your flags are technically meant to be anonymous (close votes and reviews aren't though).

Comment: okkk that would be great:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, a moderator hadn't reviewed your flag yet, so it was still active.

That's because you cast a *custom* flag for moderator attention. Those don't get automatically dismissed when the community closes a question. If you're going to flag something for closure, please use the canonical close reason flags rather than custom flags by selecting "it should be closed for another reason" in the flag dialog.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt :-)